# How to ensure that code is run when when ajax call is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm used to writing ruby where I get data, then I manipulate it, then I display it.

In javascript land, I'm getting some json, on success: manipulate and display.

I want to separate out my code to look like this

```
 $("#uiElement").click(function(){
    data = getData();
    upDateUi(data);
})

function getData(){
    var fishes;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/fishes/'+q,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            return data;
            //I don't want to manipulate the ui in this code;
            //upDateUi(data)
        },
        error: function(req,error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
    return fishes;
}
```

Comment: good for you, now what is your question?

Comment: "I don't want to manipulate the ui in this code;" Well, in all probability that's exactly what you do want but it's hard to know without an actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the logic that updates the UI from the logic that retrieves the data from the server using a `callback pattern`:

```
$("#uiElement").click(function(){
        var upDateUi = function(data) {
            /* ... logic ... */
        };

        getData(upDateUi);
})

function getData(callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/fishes/'+q,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function(req,error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
}
```

For more information on functions and scopes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

For more information on how I defined the `upDateUi` function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Recursion

Answer (score 0):

You should probably get used to event-based programming. Your code could use callbacks:

```
$("#uiElement").click(function(){
    getData(upDateUi); // make sure upDateUi is defined, it will be passed data
})

function getData(callback){
    var fishes;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/fishes/'+q,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            //I don't want to manipulate the ui in this code;
            //upDateUi(data)
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function(req,error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
    return fishes;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to remove `return data;` and define `callback` for this to do anything.

Comment: @Hamish: You are right about `return data;` - I just missed that. But when it comes to `callback`, then it is passed as an argument to `getData` and I mentioned within the comment right next to the `getData(upDateUi)` that `upDateUi` should be defined first.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what your question is, but `success` is *any* function, so this:

```
...
success: function(data){
    upDateUi(data);
},
...
```

Can be equivalently written as:

```
...
success: upDateUi,
...
```

Other than that, not sure what you mean by "I don't want to manipulate the ui in this code".

Answer (score 0):

Define a callback, and then in the success method invoke the callback:

```
$("#uiElement").click(function(){
    data = getData(upDateUi);
})

function getData(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/fishes/'+q,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if (callback !== undefined) {
               callback(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(req,error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to use a synchronous fetch, which waits for the response, but its a bad idea, as no other javascript can run (and in some browsers - nothing can run) until the response is received.

If you really, really, really want it though:

```
$("#uiElement").click(function(){
    data = getData();
    upDateUi(data);
})

function getData(){
    var fishes;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/fishes/'+q,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            fishes = data;
        },
        error: function(req,error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
    return fishes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure if is this what you want.

```
successFunction(data){
    //you can do everything here
}
errorFunction(req,error){
    console.log(error);
}
function getData(){
    var fishes;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/fishes/'+q,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: successFunction,
            error: errorFunction
        })
        return fishes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might be good for your needs:

```
var myData = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
    url: "./somewhere",
    type: 'get|post',
    async: false,
    data: { what: "ever" }
}).responseText);
```

Then you just proceed with whatever you want to do with the results.

```
 $("#uiElement").click(function(){
    var myData = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
        url: "./somewhere",
        type: 'get|post',
        async: false,
        data: { what: "ever" }
    }).responseText);
    upDateUi(myData);
})
```

Comment: There is one major drawback in this code: the call is asynchronous.

Comment: Yeah. You can't use "success" and "error" call backs. I usually have a "success: true" returned in the AJAX response which I use to check if it was successful or nor.